Comprehensive Stellar Evolution Article
Is there an article that comprehensively covers stellar evolution, from start to finish. I've found articles on this, one in an introduction to a stellar evolution model, and I am searching for more. It's fine if the article wasn't built to give a comprehensive overview, it just needs to include one.

I doubt you could do it "comprehensively" in one article.  There are plenty of books https://iopscience.iop.org/book/mono/978-0-7503-1278-3

My initial thought was Stellar Evolution at Wikipedia. Are you looking for something more scholarly-based rather than "wisdom of the crowds" based?

I think something more scholarly-based, although I have seen that article and it as halpful

How technical or comprehensive are you prepared to get? Would chapters 10-16 of Jørgen Christensen-Dalsgaard's lecture notes or chapters 9-13 of Onno Pols' lecture notes do? If you gloss over the derivations, they both describe everything that we think happens inside the stars.

@Warrick Thanks, these are helpful. The one article that I find really useful is Comprehensive analytic formulae for stellar evolution as a function of mass and metallicity at
https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/315/3/543/972062 by Jarrod et. al. I'm looking for articles more like this.
